# Google form completion confirmation email-- How to change the contact email associated with the form

Tags: forms

I set up a form for a client that generates an auto confirmation message when anyone completes the form. The issue is that the confirmation email is coming from my account. Unfortunately with Google Apps, I can't simple transfer ownership to the client as they are outside of our agencies domain. Is there a way around this? Maybe something I can add to my script to change the contact email.

I basically copied the script from a tutorial and don't really know much about code, but here's what I have:

```
function myFunction(e){
var userName = e.values[1];
var userEmail = e.values[2];
var Workshop = e.values[3];
var subject = "Registration Confirmed";
var message = "Thank you, " + userName + " for choosing the" + Workshop + " workshop. Please visit our workshop page for more information on the workshop you have chosen.";
MailApp.sendEmail (userEmail, subject, message);}
```

Answer (score 0):

When receiver click on reply button, you can default your client's email instead of yours by setting `replyTo` field and also you can change the display name of the sender by setting `name` field.

```
MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: To,
      subject: subject,
      htmlBody: message,
      name: "Client Name", //Display name
      replyTo: "Client Email Address", // Client Contact address
      inlineImages: imgMapFinal
});
```